# Find language generated by a regular grammar

Tags: formal-languages, regular-expressions

I can not solve this exercise:

**"Find the language generated by the regular grammar $G = (\{S, A, B\},\{a, b\}, P, S)$, with P given by $S\to\lambda/aB/bA,\; A\to bB,\; B\to bS$. Express it by a regular expression."**

---

It is clear that it will generate an infinite language, but by making the derivation tree, with these productions, I find it hard to see the generated language. Some help?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know how to write a nondeterministic finite automaton from a regular grammar?  It's not really necessary in this case, but it provides a systematic approach to deriving the regular expression.  Once you have the NFA, you may "see" the regular expression or translate mechanically.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi, not really `:(`. Can you help me?

Comment: Consider $S \rightarrow aB \rightarrow abS$.  What does it tell you?

Comment: Yeah I know that, it produces $ababab\ldots {(ab)}^\ast$, but $S\to aB\to abA\to abbS\to abbbA\to abbbbB\to abbbbbS\to abbbbbaB\to\ldots$ could be a possibility, right?, and I find it difficult to find a pattern for each new language that appears.

Comment: $S \rightarrow aB \rightarrow abS$, not $abA$.  If you want to use $A$, you need $S \rightarrow bA \rightarrow bbB \rightarrow bbbS$.  Eventually you need to apply $S \rightarrow \lambda$.  Every time you "go through" $S$ you've added either $ab$ or $bbb$ to your word.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi so the $L(G)=(ab)\vee{(bbb)}^\ast$?

Comment: You need parentheses around $ab \vee bbb$.

Comment: So $L(G)={(ab\vee bbb)}^\ast$? Thanks!